# Docker swarm scale and new swarm nodes issue

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, orchestration

I’m testing docker swarm on a multi node cluster.

version: 20.10.7

The point is that if I create a service with docker service create and then I join nodes everything works (I use --with-registry-auth, master node is logged in to a private registry on AWS) , it means applications are replicated on nodes with image pull and containers start.

I kill the nodes manually and scale the service to 0 with:

docker service scale myserv=0

then I when I start a new node, join it to the cluster and try scale up, the image on the node is not pulled down, it says “no such image”,
that’s strange since if I re-create the service it is able to pull the image on nodes. It is like docker service scale doesn’t login to the remote registry in the nodes.

Any tips to solve this out? it would be nice to add nodes/remove nodes and have containers scaled automatically as from the scale istruction of the service I've created.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

we do use docker swarm in our production extensively, we use ecr credential helper, check out the link [amazon-ecr-credential-helper](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/amazon-ecr-credential-helper-now-supports-amazon-ecr-public/)

Link to github : [git hub project link](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper#readme)

As described you can have a startup script on the nodes to store your credentials